# different spacing in emails using outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I prefer to have X1.5-2 spacing between luines in writing emails' using outlook 2010. I can do it every time seperately' using text formating.
how can it be my default choice for answering mails?

Answer (score 0):

To set the default spacing:

One option is to change the Stationery settings: Go to File > Options > Mail > Stationery and fonts.
Click Font > Advanced tab. 
[image]

Another option is to use Styles:

Create a style which includes the spacing settings you like. When writing an email, you can select the text that you want to change style. And then select Format Text > Styles.

Official article: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/format-email-messages-with-styles-f36f667d-f7ae-41ff-927e-17b7fc1bab38

[image]

I found [a link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/735e88da-8d2a-4fa9-86af-058eee56763a/default-styles-on-outlook-email?forum=outlook) which may be related